# codenameone - Storage file doesn't delete

Tags: java-me, storage, lwuit, codenameone

I've added storage file to my codenameone application. In some event I wanna delete specific storage file and recreate it with some old filtered data and new data. It doesn't work well on deletion.

First I create method for clear storage file in StorageManager class:

```
public void clearData(String pStorageTable){
    Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(pStorageTable);
}
```

In other class I use this method like this:

```
// load all data of specific storage file
// ...

new DBManager().clearData(ThreeTrans.DB_NAME);

// write old data with filtering of specific ID and new data
// ...
```

here is method of write data:

```
public void write(ThreeTrans pTT){
    if(store == null) {
        store = Storage.getInstance();
    }

    DB_NAME = "TT";

    if(!store.exists(DB_NAME)) {
        Hashtable depHash = new Hashtable();
        String k = "1" + pTT.getNumber();
        depHash.put(k, pTT.toString());
        store.writeObject(DB_NAME, depHash);
    }
    else {
        Hashtable depHash = (Hashtable)store.readObject(DB_NAME);

        if (!depHash.containsValue(pTT.getNumber())) {
            String k = String.valueOf(getLastKeyNumber());
            depHash.put(k, pTT.toString());
            store.writeObject(DB_NAME, depHash);
        }
    }
}
```

at first I was using this method for delete storage file:

```
public void clearData(String pStorageTable){
    if(store == null) {
        store = Storage.getInstance();
    }

    for (String str : store.listEntries()) {
        if(str.toLowerCase().startsWith(pStorageTable)) {
           store.deleteStorageFile(str);
        }
    }
}
```

and after this problem this method changed to this;

```
public void clearData(String pStorageTable){
    Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(pStorageTable);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work well"? Do you get an exception? Your final data does not have all you need?

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. No exception was raised and nothing was done.

Comment: Is this Storage file from a library? Which one?

Comment: I've added with the name of "ThreeTran". I initialized Storage file with this way: Storage store = Storage.getInstance();

Comment: As you are using codenameone, did you see this video? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q85K-nSbc_k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you didn't invoke close() on the output stream or the input stream working with the file and there is still a lock on the file. This is usually the case for such issues.

Comment: I use writeObject method for saving data to storage file and readObject for read data from storage file. Is it need to invoke close() method?

Comment: No. Can you post the code including the write code and the proper delete code? Should work pretty seamlessly. Is this on the simulator or device or both?

Comment: I edited my question. Answer of your second question is YES, I have different output for this problem and both of them (Simulator and device) are not correct.

Comment: It looks like you initialize DB_NAME at write so in the next app invocation it won't be initialized.

Comment: I did it another way to solve it (Just by replacing data). Thanks Shai